# Как сформатировать возврат метода в нужном стринговом формате Java?

Tags: java, массивы, строки, format

Подскажите, как сделать `return` `int` массива в виде строки без `[ ,  ,  , ]` имею `[100, 180, 90, 56, 65, 74, 68, 86, 99, 555555]` нужно `100 180 90 56 65 74 68 86 99 555555`

Подскажите каким методом ?

Мой код:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class WeightSort {

public static String orderWeight(String strng) {
    final String regex = "(\\d+)";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strng);

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0)));
        }
    for (int count=0 ; count<list.size(); count++ ) {
        int min = weight(list.get(count));
        int min_i = count;
        for (int c2 = count + 1; c2 < list.size(); c2++) {
            if (weight(list.get(c2)) < min) {
                min = weight(list.get(c2));
                min_i = c2;
            }
        }
        if ( count != min_i){
            int tmp = list.get(count);
            list.set(count, list.get(min_i));
            list.set(min_i, tmp);
        }
    }

}

public static int weight(int dig) {
    int num = dig;
    int sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        sum = sum + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно Вы это хотите?

```
public class integers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i : arr) {
            sb.append(i).append(' ');
        }
        System.out.println(sb.trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: последний пробел надо бы тоже `trim`-нуть

Answer (score 3):

Никаким. Скобки `[]` и запятые не являются частью массива, а обозначают его. Если вам нужно вывести элементы массива отдельно (на экран, например), то нужно решать вашу задачу в месте вывода, а не в функции, возвращающей массив.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static String getStringFromArray(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Да спасибо @Stranger in the Q. В моем случае выглядит так

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i : list) {
            sb.append(i).append(' ');
        }
        sb.delete(sb.length()-1,sb.length());
             return sb.toString();
```

Comment: просто `.trim()` )))

Comment: проще но не короче. вместо sb.delete(sb.length()-1,sb.length());
             return sb.toString(); выглядело бы String out = sb.toString(); return out.trim();

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[] arr = {100, 180, 90, 56, 65, 74, 68, 86, 99, 555555};

String str = IntStream.of(arr).mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")).trim();

System.out.println(str); // 100 180 90 56 65 74 68 86 99 555555
```